# How do I fetch CSS Coverage data using chrome dev protocol?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, code-coverage

I am working on creating a simple java class which would give me used & unused css on any given page.

```
public class coverage {

    static String str;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

        String url = "https://www.amazon.com";
        Launcher launcher = new Launcher();
        try (SessionFactory factory = launcher.launch();
                Session session = factory.create()) {
            Command command = session.getCommand();
            DOM dom = command.getDOM();
            CSS css = command.getCSS();
            session.navigate(url);
            dom.enable();
            css.enable();
            HashMap<String, List<String>> hm = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> hmUsedCSS = new HashMap<String, String>();
            css.startRuleUsageTracking();
            List<RuleUsage> list = css.stopRuleUsageTracking();
            for (RuleUsage coverage : list) {
                if (!hm.containsKey(coverage.getStyleSheetId())) {
                    hm.put(coverage.getStyleSheetId(),                               
                  css.collectClassNames(coverage.getStyleSheetId()));
                }
                if (!coverage.isUsed()) {
                    String existingContent = hmUsedCSS.get(coverage
                            .getStyleSheetId());
                    String extraContent = css.getStyleSheetText(coverage
                            .getStyleSheetId());
                    hmUsedCSS.put(coverage.getStyleSheetId(),
                            existingContent == null ? extraContent
                                    : existingContent + extraContent);
                }
            }

            for (String name : hm.keySet()) {
                List<String> value = hm.get(name);
                System.out.println("Total " + name + "=>" + value);

            }

            for (String name : hmUsedCSS.keySet()) {
                List<String> value = hm.get(name);
                System.out.println("Used CSS " + name + "=>" + value);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

As per official [documentation](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/CSS/#method-stopRuleUsageTracking), 'stopRuleUsageTracking' would tell us whether a particular CSS is being used or not by setting 'used' boolean in [RuleUsage](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/CSS/#type-RuleUsage) , but it is returning all the CSS available on the page with 'used' set to true.I figured out that the answer lies in startoffset & endoffset values as they tell us the positioning of used CSS.But I don't know how to convert these values into meaningful result of Used & Unused CSS ? Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score -1):

As I pointed out in the question , the key was to fetch coverage data as per start & end offset values.I was able to write logic to do the same & got the required list of used & Unused CSS.